# How to make a custom route in Rails? By custom I mean one that reacts to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

So essentially I've setup a route to match "products/:product", which seems to respond to a page like baseurl/products/toaster and displays the toaster product. My problem is I can't seem to use link_to to generate this path, and by that I mean I don't know how. Any help on this?

Comment: this will answer: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: This one is really good and people with this issue should definitely have a look at this, but it's slightly overkill for my current needs right now. Thanks for pointing it out, always nice to see a gem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your routes file you can do something like:

```
match "products/:product" => "products#show", :as => :product
```

Where the controller is `ProductsController` and the view is `show`

within the Products controller your have

```
  def show
    @product = Hub.find_by_name(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
  end
```

Where whatever is in the products/**:product** section will be available via params.

Then, since we used `:as` in your routes you can do this with `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to product(@product) %>
```

Where `@product` is an instance of a product or a string. This is just an example and the param can be anything you want, the same goes for controller/action. For more info you should check out [this.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the great and very clear answer, I've actually had a look through the entire routing guide but somehow seem to have missed that :as was the one that does it, cause I saw it, thought about it and then decided against it :). So thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions on this one :

```
<%= link_to 'Toaster', { :controller => 'products', :action => 'whatever', :product => 'toaster' } %>
```

But it's not really Rails Way, for that you need to add `:as => :product` at the end of your route. This will create the `product_path` helper that can be used this way :

```
<%= link_to 'Toaster', product_path(:product => 'toaster') %>
```

Comment: See I was trying the second version, but I didn't know I was supposed to add as: :product to the end of the route. Now the problem is both you and Jason answered essentially the same think. It's hard to choose but I'm giving him the correct answer because he was first and has a more complete clearer answer. Thank you very much though, it's much appreciated.